# I'm trying to enable / disable Slick Slider between a set window width (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, slick.js

I'm trying to enable Slick Slider (slick.js) to initiate only over 520px wide. Anything below that and the slides just stack (i.e. no slick). Is it possible so that it can work without refreshing the page?

I've done this, but it's really clunky:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $window = $(window),
        $slick = $('.slick'),
        toggleSlick;

    toggleSlick = function () {
        if ($window.width() > 520) {
            $slick.slick();
        } else {
            $slick.unslick();
        }
    }

    $window.resize(toggleSlick);
    toggleSlick();
});
```

I also get a `Uncaught TypeError: $slick.unslick is not a function` error in the console.

I'm using https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Answer (score 6):

I believe the way you call slick methods has changed.

Instead of `$('.slick').unslick();`

try `$('.slick').slick("unslick");`

You can also call this directly inside the responsive option in the slick options